# condição para impedir textbox null

Tags: c#, winforms

Como faço para o sistema não permitir a inserção de valores nulos dentro de um textbox, usando na condição id?

```
if(verificar se o textbox é null){
    MessangeBox.Show("digite um valor");
}
```

Comment: já tentou `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IdTextoBox.Text))` ?

Comment: Ricardo, ainda não tinha tentado nao... mas obrigado deu certo!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poderá verificar se um valor é nulo de diversas formas. Afinal, o que você considera como nulo?

Temos que considerar a diferença entre **nulo** e **vazio**, ou **whitespace**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nulo** é quando uma variável não tem nenhum valor atribuído, ou seja, quando ela nunca foi "setada". Desta forma, sempre um `NullReferenceException` (mais conhecido como Referência nula de objeto) é causada quando você tenta acessar um objeto nulo.

**Vazio** é o valor padrão do tipo. Por exemplo, numa `String`, seu valor padrão é `""`, ou seja, vazio, sem nenhum valor dentro. Portanto, ela não é **nula**, uma vez que tenha um valor ali dentro, mesmo sendo vazio.

**Whitespace** não é nenhum dos acimas, mas qualquer `String` cujo tenha apenas espaços e/ou caracteres invisíveis. Também entra na categoria de "Vazio" se estiver procurando por valores válidos.

---

### Qual eu usarei?

No meu ponto de vista da sua situação, utilizar uma verificação própria do .NET Framework conhecida como [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.7.2). Esse método irá verificar se uma `String` é **Nula**, **Vazia** ou **WhiteSpace**.

```
if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) {
    MessangeBox.Show("digite um valor");
    return;  // isso faz com que você saia do método e não execute os próximos processamentos
}
```

Assim, se sua `TextBox` tiver valor vazio, nulo ou apenas espaços, será exibida a mensagem de aviso e brevemente sairá do método.

---

Se quiser utilizar cada método individualmente, tanto para os três elementos acima, faça:

```
if(objeto == null) {
    // o objeto é nulo, não foi atribuído valor
} // ou objeto is null se a referência também for nula

if(objeto == "") {
    // o objeto não é nulo, mas é vazio
    // obs.: isso serve apenas para strings
}

if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objeto)) {
    // o objeto é nulo, vazio ou contém espaços em branco
    // obs.: isso serve apenas para strings
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, só faltou a imagem clássica: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9vg8.jpg :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Hahaha, exatamente isso. Adicionei a imagem e creditei você nos comentários da edição. xD

Comment: haha cara, muito obrigado pela explicação !!!!!!! otima referencia Tema Vs. Imagem !!!